SwiftUI equivalent of UITableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth
What is the SwiftUI equivalent of UIKit's UITableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth?

Solved my question by creating a ListReadableWidth view that wraps around a regular List.
struct ListReadableWidth<Content: View>: View {

    var content: () -> Content
    var desiredWidth: CGFloat

    init(desiredWidth: CGFloat = 685, @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.desiredWidth = desiredWidth
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                Spacer()
            }
            content()
                .frame(idealWidth: desiredWidth, maxWidth: desiredWidth)
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
    }

}

#Preview {
    ListReadableWidth {
        List {
            Text("Hi")
        }
    }
}

